# Set Button in the top of relative layout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

I need put the button above image in this relative layout but appear in the top how can i do?
So I need image and above the button. any help?

```
        <RelativeLayout style="@style/row50percent">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imgProfileBackground"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/bg_profile"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/imgProfile"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/choose_picture"
            android:id="@+id/buttonSelectPicture"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_change_picture"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

And Styles is

```
    <style name="row50percent">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:orientation">vertical</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Do you have an image of how you want it to look? It's a bit confusing, atm, what *exactly* you want

Comment: So you actually want the `Button` **below** the `ImageView`?

Comment: Can you upload an image, what you want exactly ?

Comment: there is property in RelativeLayout that is alignParentTop , Apply this on your button

Answer (score 1):

could be:

```
  <RelativeLayout style="@style/row50percent">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imgProfileBackground"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/bg_profile"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/imgProfile"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="top|center"
     >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/choose_picture"
        android:id="@+id/buttonSelectPicture"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_change_picture"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `ImageView` and `Button` inside `RelativeLayout`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.MainActivity" >

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgProfile"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ab" />

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonSelectPicture"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imgProfile"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imgProfile"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgProfile"
    android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
    android:text="Cose Picture"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

output

[image]